# $U\subseteq \mathbb C$ is simply connected if and only if it is connected and $U^c$ has no bounded components?

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness, homology-cohomology

If we define simply connected sets as connected open sets so that every cycle in them is homologous to $0$ w.r.t. them (has its interior in them) is it true that $U\subseteq \mathbb C$ is simply connected if and only if $U$ is connected and $U^c$ has no bounded components?

I have been able to prove the if part:

Assume $U$ is connected, $U^c$ has no bounded components and let $\Gamma$ be a cycle in $U$. If $S$ is a component of $U^c$ then it is unbounded and in $(\Gamma^*)^c$, hence $\eta_{\Gamma}=0$ in $S$. Because $\eta_{\Gamma}=0$ in any component of $U^c$, $\eta_{\Gamma}=0$ in $U^c$.

But how do we prove the only if part (if it is true)?

In my disposal there is a separation theorem:

If $K\subseteq U$ is compact then there exists a  homologous to $0$ w.r.t. $U$ (polygonal) cycle $\Delta$ in $U\setminus K$ so that $K$ is contained in its interior and $
\eta_{\Delta}=1$ in $K$.

So it suffices to prove that there exist open and compact sets $V,K$ respectively so that $K\subseteq V$ and $H\setminus K=U$. Is that possible?

Comment: Suppose $U^c$ has a bounded component $K$. Consider $V = U \cup K$ ...

Comment: @DanielFischer But why is $K$ compact and $V$ open?

Comment: To see that $K$ is compact, consider $\overline{K}$. Indeed, $U\cup K$ need not always be open, consider $U = \mathbb{C}\setminus \left(\{0\} \cup \left\{\frac1n : n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\right\}\right)$ and $K = \{0\}$, but if it isn't, something similar to the example must happen. However, better consider the union of $U$ and all bounded components of $U^c$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Again I do not see how $V$ is open if I consider $V=U\cup S$ where $S$ is the union of all bounded components of $U^c$ (or the closure of them)

Comment: Consider $U$ as a subset of the Riemann sphere. How many unbounded components can $U^c$ have then?

Comment: @DanielFischer I would rather avoid arguments involving $\mathbb C\cup \left\{\infty\right\}$ (which is why I am asking this characterization and not the connectedness of $S^2\setminus U$). Is that possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is possible, but it might be difficult (not that the case of $S^2$ is trivial). Let me think if I find something simple enough.

Comment: @DanielFischer It is certainly possible in the case of Runge's Theorem (pick points from every bounded component of $U^c$ instead of $S^2\setminus U$).